# cannot set my elastic load balancer with https in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I have a problem in setting my cloudformation for beanstalk with https protocl enabled.

Here is my configuration setting:

```
 configurationTemplateUI:
Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
DependsOn: BeanstalkAppUI
Properties:
  ApplicationName:
    Ref: BeanstalkAppUI
  Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Configuration Template
  OptionSettings:
  - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
    OptionName: MinSize
    Value:
      Ref: MinEc2s
  - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
    OptionName: MaxSize
    Value:
      Ref: MaxEc2s
  - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
    OptionName: EnvironmentType
    Value: LoadBalanced
  - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
    OptionName: InstanceType
    Value:
      Ref: InstanceType
  - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
    OptionName: VPCId
    Value:
      Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${BusinessUnit}-${EnvironmentInfra}-vpc-VpcId
  - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
    OptionName: Subnets
    Value:
      Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${BusinessUnit}-${EnvironmentInfra}-vpc-SubnetIdPrivate${SubnetAvNumber}
  - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
    OptionName: ELBSubnets
    Value:
      Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${BusinessUnit}-${EnvironmentInfra}-vpc-SubnetIdPublic${SubnetAvNumber}
  SolutionStackName:
    Ref: BeanstalkPackInstallationUI
```

As you  see I have all bunch of values and this works awesome when I run it. I did not find  anything on how to put the options for setting Elb with https. I can do it in console manually in beanstalk configuration in a networking section.

Can anyone shed light on that? is it possible in cloudformation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest you check out the [aws:elb:listener:listener_port](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elblistener-listener) namespace.

Here are some options I think you might find helpful:

```
- Namespace: aws:elb:listener:443
  OptionName: ListenerProtocol
  Value: HTTPS
- Namespace: aws:elb:listener:443
  OptionName: InstancePort
  Value: 80
- Namespace: aws:elb:listener:443
  OptionName: InstanceProtocol
  Value: HTTP
- Namespace: aws:elb:listener:443
  OptionName: SSLCertificateId
  Value: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:123456789012:certificate/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012
```

In this example, it configures the **ELB** to accept **HTTPS** requests and serve them with the **ACM** certificate `arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:123456789012:certificate/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012`. SSL is terminated at the ELB, and connection to the backing **EC2** instances is performed using standard HTTP.

Hope that helps.

**Edit**

For some reason the CloudFormation Elastic Beanstalk options were not being respected in the newer style [aws:elb:listener:listener_port](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elblistener-listener) options, but the asker was able to find success using the older style [aws:elb:loadbalancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elbloadbalancer) options

```
- Namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
  OptionName: LoadBalancerHTTPPort
  Value: '80'
- Namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
  OptionName: LoadBalancerHTTPSPort
  Value: '443'
- Namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
  OptionName: SSLCertificateId
  Value: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:123456789012:certificate/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I think I can add this directly in beanstalk cfn or should I create my elb separately? (Because beanstalk creates my elb automatically which makes it very easy)

Comment: That should be a drop in that Beanstalk will apply to the ELB that it creates for you.

Comment: when run it everything goes well but then when I check the beanstalk config in network panel I see that https is off. Any idea?

Comment: So secure listener prot is off and ssl certificate id has not been picked

Comment: Strange, is there any errors in the beanstalk console? The values provided are based directly on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html

Comment: No Jamie. Everything is successful and I do not see any error. Thanks a lot for the link yeah it is strange!!! So I am wondering if the cloudformation is not able to grap this option

Comment: Ok so what you said helped me a lot. Finally I got it working as follows: - Namespace: aws:elb:healthcheck
        OptionName: Interval
        Value: '10'
      - Namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
        OptionName: LoadBalancerHTTPPort
        Value: '80'
      - Namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
        OptionName: LoadBalancerHTTPSPort
        Value: '443'
      - Namespace: aws:elb:loadbalancer
        OptionName: SSLCertificateId
        Value: ... Very close to what u said thanks

Comment: Also can you you please take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751104/cannot-output-the-url-of-my-beanstalk ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe with an Application Load Balancer, the settings are:

```
        - Namespace: aws:elbv2:listener:443
          OptionName: ListenerEnabled
          Value: true
        - Namespace: aws:elbv2:listener:443
          OptionName: Protocol
          Value: HTTPS
        - Namespace: aws:elbv2:listener:443
          OptionName: SSLCertificateArns
          Value: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:123456789012:certificate/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012
```