# Cannot output the url of my beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I am having a problem with outputting beanstalk url in my cloudformation:

Here is my outputcode:

```
Outputs:
ELB:
  Description: 'The environment name'
  Value: !GetAtt BeansEnvironmentUI.EndpointURL
```

But what I see in the output in the url of loadbalancer:

```
awseb-e-k-AWSEBLoa-NP5ZWGTVP2FV-1714896666.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

This is not what I want. When I look at the beanstalk console itself I see the following:

```
myenv.prejvvvgq2.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
```

which is what I am looking for. So here is the format of the above url:

```
[nameOftheEnvironment].[IdoNotKnowWhatItIsButItIsTheSameInAllEnvironments].[region].elasticbeanstalk.com
```

So in the above format there is one thing I do not know what it is: this section

```
IdoNotKnowWhatItIsButItIsTheSameInAllEnvironments
```

So what I am gussing is it is the physical id of the beanstalk app which contains the environment. Am I right? If yes how can I get it in my cloudformation code?